# VERCEL Deployment : NotSupportedError at / deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher

Tags: django, sqlite

How do i solve this? i visited the sqlite website but is shows only version 3.45.2 version available to download whereas when hosting the website it says version 3.8.3 or higher is required? How do i update my dbsqlite version ? anyone please help and also english is not my first language so please do not use any fancy words

I tried to download from the db sqlite but it doesnt show version 3.8.3 so i didnt download it thinking it might cause errors adn also stack over flow what is your problem just let me post this

Comment: Stack overflow didnt let me upload this saying the descriptiton doesnt define the question properly or something .. why are you interfaring in my life stack overflow?? i already am overfrustated coz of coding and you make it much worse i've came here for solution not to play stupid enlgish enlgihs game

Comment: https://vercel.com/guides/is-sqlite-supported-in-vercel

Comment: Version 3.45.2 is higher than 3.8.3 (which is very old and I feel bad for anyone using a system so outdated)